# rds file not found when attempting to preview SSRS report in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

So I followed the approach using the powershell scripts to get all the information from a SSRS server and download it to my local machine.  That all worked fine.  I created a SSRS project in VS 2019, included the downloaded files and I can open and edit all the reports.  The challenge is when I go to preview the reports, I get the error message below indicating it cannot find the data source.  The data source is defined within the report as shown below:

[image]

I have seen comments regarding how to handle this when the data source is an item in the project but that doesn't apply here.  And idea what I am missing?

FYI - I am attempting to preview the report using a remote SSRS sever and I have the URL configured in the TargetServerURL of the project.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I did just notice that in the folder with my reports in the project there is a JR.rsds but I am not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: check is the report's datasource points to a shared data source (this is the most typical scenario on the server). In which case you just need to recreate the shared datasource folder.

Comment: So I see now that the DataSource within the report says to use a shared data source reference.  I will try copying that folder down from the server and see what I get.  I don't know the credentials to log into it database server is my challenge.

Comment: If you look in the web portal and then go to the Data Sources folder (View - Hidden Items if the folder is not visible) you can look at the connection details other than the password obviously.

Comment: @AlanSchofield yeah it brought all of those down as the rsds files which I couldn;t figure out how to use in a VS SSRS project and I didn't know the password but I got it now and I can test the reports.  Thanks for your help.